# Drag layers between tab-docked documents in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layers, creative-cloud

Using Photoshop CC (on Windows), I sometimes need to drag layers from one document to another. When the documents are tab-docked, I expected to be able to drag the layer over the tab and have have it "spring" open (as with folders on OS X). This does not work for me, however, and I instead have to undock one of the documents involved so that I can drag the layer onto the content of the document I want.

[image: dragging]
<sup>*dragging layer over tab and holding does not bring tab to front*</sup>

I have now seen [other](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/19918/2413) [posts](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/39195/2413) on this site that appear to say that this should work. How can I get this to work for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a *slight* trick to it.

You **can't** drag from the layers panel to a tab.

Highlight the layers you wish to move in the **Layers Panel** then click drag from the **document window** to a hidden tab. The tab should then spring forward and allow you to "drop" the layers.

Basically the drag has to be initiated from within the active tab in order to get the hidden tabs to pop forward.

Comment: Ah, thanks. I'll accept when the timer allows it.

Comment: a shame that a soft that known and expensive is not able to permit this stupid action: drag from Layer Panel, let the user tap control tab to switch canvas, and drop on the resulting document window; Every osx soft does...

Answer (score 4):

Also you can right click on selected layer(-s) and use **Duplicate layer** option

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot?

Comment: Oooooh, nice one. Right click on the layer, duplicate layer, then choose the opened document onto duplicate should happen. Thanks